# Undefined json data when i try to call it

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

First sorry for my bad english.

When I try to retrieve spedific data from json data with ajax then when i alert the data it says undefined.

This is my ajax code

```
$.ajax({
        url:'http://localhost:8080/mvcsi/public/gakubu/getUpdate',
        data:{id:id},
        method:'post',
        type:'json',
        success: function(data){
            //the problem
            console.log(data.gakubu);
        },
        error : function(e){
            console.log(e.messege);
        }
    });
```

but when I try this `console.log(data);`
it show all of my data

```
 {"code_gakubu":"8","gakubu":"AAA"}
```

[this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c3Tw.png)

then when I try to call the spesific data `console.log(data.gakubu)` it say undefined.

I also try `console.log(data[1].gakubu);` still not working

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of `console.log(data);`?

Comment: Yes, `console.log(data)` or the server side code that returns `data`

Comment: its returning  {"code_gakubu":"8","gakubu":"AAA"}

Comment: @Eddie ,
{"code_gakubu":"8","gakubu":"AAA"} this is the result of the code in my console

Comment: If that is the result then `console.log(data.gakubu);` should work. Can you post a screenshot (**image**) when you do `console.log(data);`?

Comment: @Eddie , https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c3Tw.png this is the result

Comment: @Eddie ,https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c3Tw.png this is thw result screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the screenshot, the `data` is a string. You can use `dataType: "json"` to receive objects

Like:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://localhost:8080/mvcsi/public/gakubu/getUpdate',
    data:{id:id},
    method:'post',
    dataType: "json",  //<--- Use dataType instead of type
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data.gakubu);
    },
    error : function(e){
        console.log(e.messege);
    }
});
```

Doc: [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: it didnt work because it is a string type? not an array?

Comment: Yes. Basically,  `data` is a string and has no `gakubu` property.

Comment: Still undefined?

Comment: yes, when i do  console.log(data.gakubu); also when i do  console.log(data); still showing string data

Comment: Did you change `type` to `dataType`?

Comment: can you tell me the different of type and datatype

Comment: `type` should be `get` or `post`. An alias of (`method`) as per the jQuery doc.